# Как правильно вывести текст заголовка элемента?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно для каждого элемента li.item в списке ul.list, найти и вывести в консоль текст заголовка элемента (теге h2) и количество элементов в категории (всех вложенных в него элементов li). Например для первой категории получится:

Категория: Животные
Количество элементов: 4
Категория: Продукты
Количество элементов: 3
Вот что у меня выводит консоль:

(3) ["Категория: Животные Количество элементов: 4", "Категория: Животные Количество элементов: 3", "Категория: Животные Количество элементов: 5"]

У меня считает количество элементов в категории нормально а,  заголовок выводит только  животные. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема) Вот мое решение

```js
'use strict';
const categoriesUl = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll("ul#categories>li.item")
  );
  console.log(`В списке ${categoriesUl.length} категории`);
  const categoriesList = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll("ul#categories li.item ul ")
  );
  const categoriesArr = [];
  categoriesList.forEach(element => {
    categoriesArr.push(
      `Категория: ${
        document.querySelector("h2").textContent
      } / Количество элементов: ${element.children.length}`
    );
  });
  console.log(categoriesArr);
```

```html
<ul id="categories">
  <li class="item">
    <h2>Животные</h2>

    <ul>
      <li>Кот</li>
      <li>Хомяк</li>
      <li>Лошадь</li>
      <li>Попугай</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h2>Продукты</h2>

    <ul>
      <li>Хлеб</li>
      <li>Петрушка</li>
      <li>Творог</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h2>Технологии</h2>

    <ul>
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
      <li>React</li>
      <li>Node</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А если вы выводимый текст в одну строку напишете, что-то изменится? Пробовали?

Comment: не совсем поняла как написать выводимый текст в одну строку извините

Comment: Где вы пушите строки в массив `categoriesArr` строку напишите в одну линию без переводов строк и слэша , просто пробелы используйте, чтоб отделить текст. Какой будет результат?

Comment: результат тот же(

Comment: А можете результат показать? Что в консоли?

Comment: (3) ["Категория: Животные Количество элементов: 4", "Категория: Животные Количество элементов: 3", "Категория: Животные Количество элементов: 5"]

Comment: так выводит консоль я уже просто запуталась в этом всем(

Comment: Ну вы и нас всех запутали. Потому что пока я не увидел вывод, я не понимал, что именно у вас не получается. Лучше добавить вывод в консоль в ваш вопрос, так будет яснее всем, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: я поняла , сейчас исправлю

Comment: У вас везде буду Животные потому, что `document.querySelector("h2")` возвращает ПЕРВЫЙ элемент, который найдется в DOM. А он равен `Животные`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98867/discussion-between-hzybodska-and-daniyal-lukmanov).

Comment: Мне с телефона сложно ответ написать. Вам нужно по коллекции `categoriesUl` пробежать циклом, внутри которого вы будете выводить его `h2`, считать количество и выводить его в той же строке. Лучше разбить на две функции для читабельности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, (element) => {
    const title = element.querySelector('h2').innerHTML;
    const itemsLength = element.querySelectorAll('li').length;
    console.log(`Категория: ${title} / Количество элементов: ${itemsLength}`);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

```
const ul = Array.from(document.querySelector('#categories').children);
for (let elem of ul) {
    let category = elem.firstElementChild.textContent;   
    let quantityElem = elem.lastElementChild.children.length;
    console.log(`Категория: ${category} \nКоличество элементов: ${quantityElem}`);
};
```